# Equivalent definitions of cointegration rank for VAR(2)

Tags: time-series, self-study, cointegration

Let us have Vector Autoregression

$$\begin{cases}I: y_t = 2 + 1.3 y_{t-1} + e_{1t} \\
J: x_t = 3 - 0.3 y_{t-1} +1.3 x_{t-1} + e_{2t}   \end{cases}$$

I am asked to find the cointegration rank and check whether the long-run time-series correlation exist.

I know that if there is $\lambda$ such that $I+\lambda J$ is  stationary then VAR is of cointegration rank 1, else the rank is 2.

I have done the ECM expression for the process and get

$\Delta Y_t = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0.3 & 0 \\ -0.3 & 0.3 \end{pmatrix}Y_{t-1}+ \begin{pmatrix} e_{1t} \\ e_{2t} \end{pmatrix}$

It's said in my coursebook that if the rank of the matrix i ECM expression is full, then we treat the model as VAR, and if the rank is 2, then the series are cointegrated. Is it correct that those two processes are not cointegrated?

How is it so that the matrix rank=1 $\Leftrightarrow$ $\lambda$ exists?